# FIX 4.4 MarketDataRequest Conditionally Required Field Missing (299)

Tags: python, fix-protocol

I wrote a program that sends the following

```
 to App: 8=FIX.4.4|9=156|35=V|34=2|49=id|52=sometime|56=id1|146=1|55=EURUSD|460=4|167=FOR|262=1|263=1|264=1|265=0|267=2|269=0|269=1|10=114|
```

I receive this. I get the bid and the offer as expected:

```
 from App 8=FIX.4.4|9=217|35=W|34=4|49=id1|52=sometime|56=id|42=sometime1|55=EURUSD|262=1|268=2|269=0|270=1.12438|271=50000|269=1|270=1.12442|271=50000|10094=sometime2|10=002|
```

But as I request snapshot + update on full refresh, it sends back the following;

```
to App: 8=FIX.4.4|9=118|35=j|34=3|49=id|52=sometime|56=id1|45=2|58=Conditionally Required Field Missing (299)|372=W|380=5|10=210|
```

Data Dictionary of my broker is the following: [DataDictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoxrs.png)

> UseDataDictionary=Y
>
> ValidateUserDefinedFields=N # tried with Y, same
>
> DataDictionary=C:\Users\Documents\FIX44.xml

Any idea of what I did wrong please?

Thank you folks!

Comment: You've given us every message except the one we need to see: the snapshot+update request that led to the first reject.    However, your first resource should be the counterparty documentation: they will tell you what your V message needs to look like, and it may require some customizations to the standard FIX DataDictionary.

(Unless I'm overlooking it, 299 doesn't belong to V in the standard DD, so your counterparty may have added it.)

Comment: I have edited my question with the code

Comment: No you didn't.  You pasted some code, but you still didn't paste the request message that I was asking about.  But never mind, I decided I don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your counterparty's documentation for what fields they expect you to send in the MarketDataRequest (35=V) message.

In the default DataDictionary, QuoteEntryID (tag 299) doesn't belong to MarketDataRequest or in any of the repeating groups it contains.  This means that your counterparty has made a DD customization and added it somewhere.

So your main mistake is that you are not looking at your counterparty's docs, and your local DD is not in sync with theirs.  **That latter part is not burning you here in this question, but it *will* burn you later.  Get your DD in sync!**

**Back to this issue:**  Sure, you're adding QuoteEntryID to the message, but you're adding it to the top-level of the message body, and your counterparty probably isn't looking for it there.  If you look again at the default DataDictionary, QuoteEntryID always belong to a group, so your counterparty probably wants it in in a group also.  You just need to read their docs to find out which group it is.

**TLDR: Counterparties always customize the DataDictionary -- always read your counterparty's docs!**

Comment: What did I miss? I have asked for their DataDictionary cause I have not found it on the website. Otherwise I look at fields required and it looks like I have included everything. Perhaps I did not fully understand your answer though

Comment: You're adding QuoteEntryID to the top-level body of the message, but I'm fairly sure your counterparty is looking for it inside a repeating group.  Of course, you can't put it in a group until you find out which group it should go in, and in what position, and that's why you need their docs.

Comment: Okay! I get what you mean now. Thank you!